# To assign a prototype to Number, should I use Function.prototype or Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript

I want to extend the type 'Number' with a new function and hence I have to define a prototype.  When I think about this, I get a bunch of questions:

1. Does Number inherit from both Object.prototype as well as Function.prototype?
2. Is 'Number' an 'Object' or a 'Function'?
3. When should I define an object as a prototype for Number?  Does it make sense?

Comment: 1. no, 2. no, 3. Number already has a prototype, 4. no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- True. `Number instanceof Object` returns true also `Function instanceof Object` returns true. So Number has all methods that Object and Function has.

2- Number is a function. `typeof Number` returns "function".

3- If you want to add a method to Number's prototype, just use

```
Number.prototype.METHOD_NAME = function() {
    // your logic
}
```

Then you can call your method on all numbers like `1..METHOD_NAME()`

Answer (score 2):

The number methods are already contained in `Number.prototype` to add own methods just do:

```
Number.prototype.addOne = function(){
return this.valueOf() + 1;
};

1..addOne() // 2
```

Your question confuses me as I am not sure whether by Number you mean the number constructor which is just an ordinary function or number primitives.

Number primitives are not objects and as such don't inherit anything, when you do `1..addOne()` the number is converted to an object and then the `.addOne` is found in the `Number.prototype` and called with `this` set to the object form of the number.

Comment: Esailija:  Your answer partially answers my quesion.  Will'.addOne' be found for the objects or for a subset of objects (I guess "1"..addOne() will not work).  If it is for a subset of objects, my question is how Number.prototype is mapped to that subset.

Comment: It will be found on number objects only. And `1..addOne() // 2` works that's why it's in my answer. `1.addOne()` is a syntax error because the dot is a decimal point not a property access

Comment: Thanks.  Just to complete the answer, it applies to only number primitives since this is a general-purpose constructor to create wrapper classes for number primitives.  For objects, string, array etc, three are specific general-purpose constructs viz., Object, String, Array

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan, what do you mean? I only talked about the code my answer. If you have some code that does what you describe, please edit it into your question :P

Comment: It is so challenging to understand each other, isn't it? :-).  When I asked the original question, I was not aware of the different types of objects.  Therefore I was answering my own question of how addOne is able to identify Function Objects (in this case the wrapper class created for 1).  I was telling that "1" inherits from String.prototype & not from Number.prototype and hence "what Esailija says is true".  If I am still not clear, i am giving up :-D.

Comment: To simplify, let's consider primitives as objects. `"1"` is a string, therefore you can only call methods on it that are in the `String.prototype`. `1` is a number, therefore you can only call methods on it that are in the `Number.prototype`. Both are objects (not rly but sigh), so they both have what `Object.prototype` has. They don't have what `Function.prototype` has, that's for functions such as `parseFloat`, `parseInt`, `Number`, `String`, `addOne` etc. There is no wrapper class for anything, the method `addOne` is directly called on a `Number` and works because `addOne` is in the `Numbe`

Comment: @RajkumarMasaniayan, `Number.prototype` (continue from last message)

Answer (score 1):

`Number` itself is an ordinary function.
You can assign properties to it directly.

If you want to extend number *instances*, you should assign to `Number.prototype`.

Comment: SLaks: I guess Number is a built-in ordinary function.  What are the other functions that have 'Number' as the prototype?  What are the prototypes of 'number literals'?

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: :-).  Let me try again.  If I do 

    Number.prototype.addOne = function (n) {
        return this.valueOf() + 1;
    }

I guess **1.addOne()** is valid whereas **"1".addOne()** is not valid.  Is that correct?

If the above understanding is correct, my question is, how does one type inherit addOne and the other doesn't.

Comment: Correct. `"1"` is a `String`.

Comment: `1.addOne()` is a syntax error  because the dot is a decimal point not a property access. Workarounds: `1..addOne()` `1 .addOne()` `(1).addOne()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your questions. If I really thought monkey-patching `Number` was a good idea, I'd just do:

```
Number.prototype.newfunc = function(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Number, Function and Object are all General-purpose constructors.  Number inherit from Function which in turn inherits from Object.  Number constructor should be used for number primitive to create wrapper object and invoke associated functions.